# Debezium kafka connect no records produced

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying out Kafka and have got the io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector registered correctly as the connector returns

```
{
    "name": "test_connector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

When I enable CDC on the table from the logs it appears to work

```
INFO Snapshot ended with SnapshotResult [status=COMPLETED, offset=SqlServerOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=SourceInfo [serverName=TestServer, changeLsn=NULL, commitLsn=0000006d:00000a46:0003, eventSerialNo=null, snapshot=FALSE, sourceTime=2022-02-28T04:51:31.813Z], snapshotCompleted=true, eventSerialNo=1]] (io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator)
```

However edits to the table do not seem to be picked up yet I can confirm the edits are making it into the change control table.

```
 INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=test_connector-0} Either no records were produced by the task since the last offset commit, or every record has been filtered out by a transformation or dropped due to transformation or conversion errors. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
```

Once I confirm this my next step is to see if I can stream the changes using KSQL

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add your connector configuration? most likely we can solve it after giving it a look.

Comment: Have you ever check the status after registration? [`curl localhost:8083/connectors/test_connector/status | jq
`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/monitoring.html)

Comment: @C.C.Hsu <topic_name>/status does not work for me, any suggestions why?